# Calling a library function with a twist - modifying some of its behaviour

Tags: c++, hook, octave, shared, backtrace

I am trying to embed the octave library within a larger program. It is required that I can start and stop the octave interpreter at will from this larger program. However, the only function to stop the octave interpreter cleanly also calls exit(), which kills the larger program also. The octave library function is clean_up_and_exit().

Ideally I would like to call just the cleanup part (do_octave_atexit), and skip the call to exit.

I tried the following:

1) calling do_octave_atexit, however the symbol is not exported in the octave library. I Tried to access it anyway but to no avail.

2) I tried hooking into the call to exit, and replacing it with a function that does not exit, via ld_preload. This messed up everything as all other calls to exit were hooked also.

3) I tried to detect when exit was being called by octave only to prevent it only then, by detecting the calling function with a call to backtrace. This for some reason did not show what i would expect to be the true call hierarchy. For some reason it only showed the main function, and no contents of the call hierarchy through the octave library. So in was not able to detect the call coming from octave.

The Code I am using to call the octave functions looks like:

```
//
// Octave Setup Functions
//
extern "C" void oct_init (const char * path) {
  string_vector argv (2);
  argv(0) = "embedded";
  argv(1) = "-q";

  octave_main (2, argv.c_str_vec (), 1);
  if(strlen(path) > 1) {
    oct_addpath(path);
  }
}

extern "C" void oct_exit (void) {
  printf("Exiting!");
  clean_up_and_exit (1,1);
}
```

The key function here is clean_up_and_exit - which is implemented in the octave source as:

```
void clean_up_and_exit (int retval, bool safe_to_return)
{
  do_octave_atexit ();

  if (octave_link::exit (retval))
  {
    if (safe_to_return)
      return;
    else
     {
       gnulib::sleep (86400);
     }
 }
 else
 {
   if (octave_exit)
     (*octave_exit) (retval);
 }
}
```

So the above code calls the function I want (do_octave_atexit) but then proceeds to call *octave_exit - which is a function pointer to exit().

Ideally I want to either a) prevent this call to exit(), or b) trap the call when it comes from octave only and prevent it, and allow it when it comes from other sources. I have not been able to do a) or b) so far!

So at this point I am out of ideas. I could recompile octave, but this solution is supposed to work with a stock octave install.

This only had to work on a linux/gcc environment.

Any and all suggestions to this very tricky issue greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you show your example code, the one where you start the octave interpreter, exit, and causes it to also exit your own program?

Comment: How about running octave as a separate process and communicating to it via pipe?

Comment: @fukanchik That sounds very interesting as an alternative. Do you have any examples how that can be done from C? Can the pipe be opened as a 'handle' that persists between multiple calls until it is closed?

Comment: @carandraug Thanks for replying. I added the code inline in the original question. I call the function oct_exit - which calls clean_up_and_exit, when then calls the stdlib exit() via a function pointer, and my program quits –

Answer (score 1):

You will have to fork, and run Octave on a separate process.  Here's a simple example on how to do it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <octave/parse.h>
#include <octave/toplev.h>

int
main_octave (void)
{
  string_vector argv (2);
  argv(0) = "embedded";
  argv(1) = "-q";

  octave_main (2, argv.c_str_vec (), 1);

  octave_value_list out = feval ("pi", octave_value_list (0), 1);
  if (! error_state && out.length () > 0)
    std::cout << "pi is " << out(0).double_value () << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "invalid\n";

  clean_up_and_exit (0);
}

int
main (void)
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0)
    main_octave ();
  else if (pid > 0)
    {
      std::cout << "Parent process going for a nap" << std::endl;
      sleep (5);
    }
  else
    {
      std::cout << "Unable to fork()" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
  std::cout << "Leaving standalone application" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Which on my system returns:

```
$ mkoctfile --link-stand-alone embedded.cc -o embedded
$ ./embedded
Parent process going for a nap
pi is 3.14159
Leaving standalone application
```

So you can keep running your application after exiting the Octave process. Of course, if you want to start and stop Octave multiple times, then you will have to fork multiple times.  Also, I'd recommend you ask such things on the Octave help mailing list, you're more likely to get helpful answers faster there.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did submit this question to Octave-General mailing list, though unfortunately it did not get much (any!) traction there.    One thing I do not understand with the fork method is how to access the child process repeatedly from the parent process. The seprate start and exit functions from the original were because the parent starts octave, then executes N calles to feval (which are not pre-determined at compile time) and then exits octave. This process may repeat many times. So your method would work - but I think I would need a 'handle' to communicate with the child-process?